# Meteorjs aldeed meteor-tabular with publishcomposite

Tags: meteor

sorry if my question is too easy, I'm starting with Meteor

I'm trying to use aldeed:tabular, but isn't working for me.
I have the following configuration, but the columns with title "Ingrediente", "Updated By" are empty in the DataDatable

[image: screenshot]

/app/lib/controllers/preco_ingredientes_controller.js

```
TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

PrecoIngredientes.helpers({
  ingrediente: function () {
    console.log("PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:" + JSON.stringify(this));
    return Ingredientes.find(this.ingredienteId).name;
    // return Ingrediente;
  },
  updated: function () {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.updatedById});
    console.log("user:" + JSON.stringify(user));
    return user && user.name;
    // return Ingrediente;
  },

});

TabularTables.PrecoIngredientes = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "PrecoIngredientes",
  collection: PrecoIngredientes,
  pub: "precoIngredientes_Composite",
  columns: [
    {data: "quantidade", title: "Quantidade"},
    {data: "preco", title: "Preco"},
    {data: "ingrediente()", title: "Ingrediente"},
    {data: "updated()", title: "Updated By"},

  ]
});
```

/app/server/publish.js

```
Meteor.publishComposite('precoIngredientes_Composite',function (tableName, ids, fields) {
    check(tableName, String);
    check(ids, Array);
    check(fields, Match.Optional(Object));

    this.unblock(); // requires meteorhacks:unblock package
    return {
    find: function() {
       this.unblock(); // requires meteorhacks:unblock package
       console.log("Publish:" + JSON.stringify(PrecoIngredientes.findOne()));
        return PrecoIngredientes.find({});
    },  
    children: [ 
        {
            find: function(precoIngrediente) {
              this.unblock(); 
                return Meteor.users.find(
                    { _id: precoIngrediente.updatedById },
                    { limit: 1});
            }
        },
        {
            find: function(precoIngrediente) {

              // console.log("child2:");
              this.unblock(); 
                return Ingredientes.find({ _id: precoIngrediente.ingredienteId });
            }
        }
    ]
  }
});
```

/app/client/templates/preco_ingredientes/preco_list/preco_ingredientes_list_new.html

```
{{> tabular table=TabularTables.PrecoIngredientes class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
```

/app/lib/collections/preco_ingredientes.js

```
PrecoIngredientes = new Mongo.Collection('precoIngredientes');

var schemasPrecoIngrediente = new SimpleSchema({
    ...,
    ingredienteId: {
    label: "Ingrediente",
    type:  String,
    optional: true,

    autoValue: function() {
      if ( this.isSet ){
        return this.value;
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    },
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput:{
        placeholder: 'Select One'
      },
      label: "Ingrediente",
      selectOnBlur: true,
      type: "select2",
      options: function() {
       var list = [];
       list.push({label: "", value: ""});
        var ingredientesList = Ingredientes.find();
        ingredientesList.map(function(ingrediente) {
          list.push({
            label: ingrediente.name,
            value: ingrediente._id
          });
        });
        return list;
      }
    }
  },
    updatedById: {
        type: String,
        label: "Updated by",
        autoValue: function() {
            if (!this.value)
                return this.userId;
        },
        optional: true
    },
...
});
```

Chrome Console

```
    PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:{"preco":79.78,"quantidade":123,"_id":"FWuxM5wKE7969kkMk"}
user:undefined
PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:{"preco":1111.22,"quantidade":123,"_id":"g2NMe7DwCxPQWivD9"}
user:undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Edit1

I Got the Entire Json from PrecoIngrediente directly from MongoDB

```
    {
    "_id" : "FWuxM5wKE7969kkMk",
    "ingredienteId" : "kwqRCm8kaNCofmPqN",
    "quantidade" : 123,
    "preco" : 79.78,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-01T20:24:38.304Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-01T20:24:38.304Z"),
    "updatedById" : "XBGiQDNdW25JdMHew"
}
```

Edit2

I added a Log in the publishcomposite

Server Log:

```
I20151012-11:18:31.611(-3)? Publish: {"_id":"FWuxM5wKE7969kkMk", "ingredienteId":"kwqRCm8kaNCofmPqN","quantidade":123,"preco":79.78,"createdAt":"2015-10-01T20:24:38.304Z","updatedAt":"2015-10-01T20:24:38.304Z","updatedById":"XBGiQDNdW25JdMHew"}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see from your console output of

```
console.log("PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:" + JSON.stringify(this));
```

that `this` has the value of:

```
{"preco":1111.22,"quantidade":123,"_id":"g2NMe7DwCxPQWivD9"}
```

But in your `updated` helper you are referring to `this.userId` which is going to be undefined. Therefore

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
```

will also be undefined and

```
console.log("user:" + JSON.stringify(user));
```

will fail with

```
user:undefined
```

Comment: Thank You Michel. The Entire Json from the PrecoIngrediente is: {
    "_id" : "g2NMe7DwCxPQWivD9",
    "quantidade" : 123,
    "preco" : 1111.22,
    "ingredienteId" : "",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-01T20:26:21.647Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-01T20:26:21.647Z"),
    "updatedById" : "XBGiQDNdW25JdMHew"
}. I got directly from MongoDB

Comment: But still no `userId` key in there. That's the important bit.

Comment: Thank you @Michel-floyd , I didn't saw my error. I Fixed it to "updatedById" in my preco_ingredientes_controller.js, and now is the same as my MongoDB object, but the field "updatedById" is not logged in my console.

Comment: Hello @Michel Floyd, I added a Log in my publish.sh with a FindOne, to see if the Value is returned, and with FindOne is the value returned.

Comment: Are you still getting `user:undefined`?

Comment: unfortunately yes > PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:{"preco":79.78,"quantidade":123,"_id":"FWuxM5wKE7969kkMk"}
preco_ingredientes_controller.js?7882ccdf6c9050b3e5063a9e65d475721657a1b1:53 user:undefined
preco_ingredientes_controller.js?7882ccdf6c9050b3e5063a9e65d475721657a1b1:47 PrecoIngredientes.helpers this.ingredienteId:{"preco":1111.22,"quantidade":123,"_id":"g2NMe7DwCxPQWivD9"}
preco_ingredientes_controller.js?7882ccdf6c9050b3e5063a9e65d475721657a1b1:53 user:undefined

Comment: I added the log in the Question

Comment: Unless your code has changed my answer remains the same: there is no `userId` key in `this` so you can't search on it. Do `console.log(this.userId)` right before `var user = ` to verify.

Comment: I updated the code and mongodbObject in the question